# Dynamically adding statements to a method

Tags: ruby

I have a class Foo:

```
class Foo

    def a
        "something" if true
    end

end
```

I want an `add_statement` method to add new statements to the method, keeping the old implementation. Is it possible?

I want to do something like this:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.extend_method(:a, &block)
```

so now the source of my `a` method should be something like this:

```
    def a
        "something" if true
        &block
    end
```

where `&block` is the code I passed as argument in `extend_method`.

Comment: `define_method(:add_statement, instance_method(:a))`

Comment: It seems that you want to create a new method that contains the statements in `a` plus additional statements. Is that what you mean? Please edit and add an example. ("dynamically" in the title is misspelled.)

Comment: I edited it, check it out

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea. It is a potentially uncontrollable code at runtime. Maybe you should think another way. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Too many times we get asked about an "[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)", where the question is about Y which is the implementation of a solution, when it should be X, which is the problem and how it could be solved. This question has the smell of a "Y". Please explain what you want to do. Also, don't add "EDIT" or "UPDATE", instead simply incorporate the information where it belongs in the question as if you'd included it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `alias_method_chain`, or `Module#prepend`.

There are many tutorials / documentation about them on the net, for example "[AVOIDING ALIAS_METHOD_CHAIN IN RUBY](http://www.wedesoft.de/no-alias-method-chain.html)" or "[Module.prepend: a super story](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/module-prepend-a-super-story)".

For your specific example (when you want to extend the function outside of the class), you have to use `alias_method_chain`, added in a new module, and included in your original class using `Foo.send`.

You can find more details and examples in "[When to use alias_method_chain](http://erniemiller.org/2011/02/03/when-to-use-alias_method_chain/)".

Comment: `Module#prepend` is a good solution I've used for similar situations where I needed to change behavior of `require` and `require_relative`. Also, instead of "this or this", provide usable anchor text that allows people to quickly and easily see where the link will take them without having to actually click it to see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an aspect oriented example:

```
require 'aspector'

class Foo
  def a
    puts "in Foo.a"
  end
end

aspect = Aspector do
  before :a do
    puts 'this should print first'
  end

  after :a do |result_of_a|
    puts 'this should print last'
  end
end

puts "\n\nplain instance"
foo = Foo.new
foo.a

puts "\n\napply to an instance"
aspect.apply(foo)
foo.a

puts "\n\napply to all instances of Foo"
aspect.apply(Foo)
Foo.new.a
```

You will need to 'gem install aspector'.